# What is the proper word for something that can be instantiated?

Tags: terminology, programming

While reading [a RFC for the Rust programming language](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/79fa41c1722fe32b1b45d3069b863a8f83bee996/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md), I came across this paragraph:

> Given the above code, there is no way for `bar` to choose a return type `X`
> that could fundamentally differ between instantiations of `Self`
> -while still being instantiable with an arbitrary `U`.

The word **instantiable** caught my eye and my spell checker agreed that it wasn't a word. However, neither was the alternative I'd expected it to be: **instantiatable**.

[Merriam-Webster defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instantiate) **instantiate** as:

> to represent (an abstraction) by a concrete instance

Which seems to match up well with the general programming concept as I understand it, so I don't believe deep programming knowledge is required to weigh-in on this formation of the English word.

Comment: http://www.yourdictionary.com/instantiable

Comment: **instantiatee** or **instantiate-ee**: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ee

For future reference, anytime you need to indicate the recipient/object of some action or doer, just add -ee to the end of it

Comment: Spell checkers are not reliable sources for determining that something is "not a word." You should check a dictionary. (Even if a word is not in the dictionary, it does not mean that it is "not a word." Physical dictionaries have limited space, and even digital dictionaries need to have entries added to them by people who have a limited amount of time. They can't list all the words that can be formed with highly productive affixes such as *un-,* *re-,* *-ly,* and *-able.*)

Comment: @sumelic certainly! I don't mean to suggest that absence from a spell checker or a dictionary is the final word in the matter — if I did I wouldn't have bothered to ask a question and just assumed it didn't exist. I'll admit I don't know much of the provenance of yourdictionary or even of Wikionary, so I don't know how much to trust one or the other.

Comment: @V0ight Wouldn't that apply *after* instantiation? In this case, I'm looking for something that has the *ability* to be instantiated, but may not have been.

Comment: To clarify: I wasn't trying to be sarcastic with the quotation marks around "not a word" in my previous post. I just didn't want to use that phrase without some kind of indicator that it is a very problematic concept. I can understand being leery of online dictionaries, but what criteria would you use to determine whether or not you would be comfortable using a word?

Comment: @Shepmaster ~ *instantiatee* just refers to that which is instantiated; it can apply to anything that is capable of being instantiated or anything that already IS instantiated.

Comment: @sumelic *what criteria would you use to determine whether or not you would be comfortable using a word* — [tchrist's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/337697/185857) goes a long way for me. I appreciate seeing existing patterns and being able to apply a rule to extrapolate new variants (is it a surprise I am a programmer?). Being provided with a term like "English derivational morphology" also gives me a bit more meat to research further on my own. And let's face it, it also sounds nicely authoritative. ^_^

Comment: [*In this chapter, we take modularity several steps further by creating what Java calls **Instantiable** classes.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22what+Java+calls+Instantiable+classes%22) ***My*** crappy spell-checker doesn't even believe ***modularity*** is a valid word. It may be worth noting that OED's first citation for ***instantiate*** is 1949. Spell-checkers are often implemented using out-of-date (i.e. - *cheap*) lists of valid words. They exist to remind you to check whether you might have made a silly mistake, not to *teach* you right from wrong.

Comment: ... And doesn't even OED only define 600 000-odd words? There are supposed to be over a million now in the English lexicon (though who worked this out, I don't know. Probably a computer.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OED defines *odd* used after a number as I think you meant: "‘or so’; ‘or thereabouts’" which is what I've always understood. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odd) has "somewhat **more** than the indicated approximate quantity, extent, or degree // *300-odd pages*" Is there a BrE/AmE difference? I use "some 300 pages" or "300-odd pages" to mean *about 300*.

Comment: P.S. Lexico has both meanings.

Comment: @DjinTonic [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/odd) has  '2. Being in excess of the indicated or approximate number, extent, or degree. Often used in combination: _invited 30-odd guests_. Work _that_ one out. 'Over what I estimate to be 30 (but which a better estimator might put at 26). 27, in fact.' Pragmatics usually leads one to interpret 'six million' as 'about six million' anyway. I just add the -odd (hyphenated as per Grice) to emphasise the estimation involved. // Worth a question?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, will do. I was toying with that idea, but wanted confirmation that something about this was indeed strange--thank you.

Comment: I'd get the OED judgement as a prerequisite.

Answer (score 3):

The computer program you are using is buggy, because it doesn't know about English derivational morphology, let alone Latin derivational morphology whence this all originates.

We have plenty of pairs that work this way:

- affiliate, affiliable
- appreciate, appreciable
- appropriate, appropriable
- associate, associable
- denunciate, denunciable
- differentiate, differentiable
- dissociate, dissociable
- enunciate, enunciable
- excoriate, excoriable
- excruciate, excruciable
- expiate, expiable
- inappropriate, inappropriable
- negotiate, negotiable
- propitiate, propitiable

That's just how these things work. Spelling checkers are fundamentally incapable of deciding whether something is not a word.

Comment: As a programmer, I would quibble with the usage of the word "buggy", especially when it comes down to patterns and rules as complicated as the English language. As a human, however, I understand what you are saying ^_^

Answer (score 0):

### instantiatable

OR

### instantiable

See:

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instantiable#English
- https://www.wordsense.eu/instantiatable/
- https://etymologeek.com/eng/instantiatable