# Does "300-odd pages" mean "about 300 pages" or "somewhat more than 300 pages"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I've always understood the adjective *-odd* used in combination to mean *about*, as in "She read *300-odd pages* and then stopped." After reading a comment by Edwin Ashworth in another [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337696/what-is-the-proper-word-for-something-that-can-be-instantiated?noredirect=1#comment1470395_337696) ("And doesn't even OED only define 600 000-odd words?") I looked up definitions of *-odd* and was surprised to find that they differ, with three meanings:

I. More than the number indicated
II. Approximately the number indicated
III. Either more than or approximately the number indicated

---

**I. More than the number indicated**

(a)

> Somewhat **more** than the indicated **approximate** quantity, extent,
> or degree —usually used in combination *300-odd pages* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odd)

(b)

> *(In combination)* Used to designate an indefinite quantity **more** than the quantity specified in round numbers: *fifty-odd pounds*. Collins (print)

(c)

> With a relatively small number **over** that specified (usually in
> hyphenated compounds) *twenty-odd children*. *Webster's New World
> Dictionary*

(d)

> **Additional to** a whole mentioned in round numbers, or to any other
> specified whole: following *and* when it takes the place of a unit
> appended to a ten.
>
> A fortnight and *odd* days. *Shak.*, R and J, i.3.15.
>
> Eighty-*odd* years of sorrow have I seen. *Shak.* Rich. III. iv.1.96.
> [*The Century Dictionary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Century_Dictionary_The_Century_dicti/FovPjGlWDUEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=century%20dictionary%20odd&pg=PA4081&printsec=frontcover)

(e)
Edwin pointed out the curious take on this in the [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=odd):

> Being **in excess** of the indicated or approximate number, extent, or
> degree. Often used in combination: *invited **30-odd** guests*.

*[Webster's II New College Dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Webster_s_II_New_College_Dictionary/vsaXzwMndS8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=webster%27s%20odd&pg=PA758&printsec=frontcover)*, also published by Houghton Mifflin, has an almost identical definition.

(Would you really use *odd* with a number that was not an approximation, e.g., "There were **123-odd** books fitting the description"?)

(f)

> The expression + *odd* refers to a relatively small amount **over**
> that specified; e.g. *300 odd* means 'slightly over 300' [D. Biber, S.
> Johansson, and G. Leech; *Grammar of Spoken and Written English*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Grammar_of_Spoken_and_Written_English/qSlHEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=twenty-odd%20after%20a%20number%20can%20mean%20about%20or%20more%20than&pg=PA116&printsec=frontcover)

(g)
And, for good measure, a textbook published by Routlege:

> Let's look at some more sentences and see how the hyphen changes the
> meaning of the sentence.
>
> 1. (Thirty odd) students tried out for the play.
>
> *We can say "thirty odd" students, which denotes that those thirty students are peculiar.
>
> Or we can say "thirty-odd" students, which
> means **30+** students.* [D. Crovitz and M. Devereaux; *More Grammar
> to Get Things Done*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/More_Grammar_to_Get_Things_Done/Yh24DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=thirty-odd%20means&pg=PT129&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

(h)

> *Informal*: a little more than a particular number — used in combination with a number
>
> *The book's only 100-odd pages long. [=only slightly more than 100 pages long]* [The Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/odd)

(i)

> In other cases, the approximate expression tells us we are
> slightly under the mentioned quantity, but leaves undetermined how
> much. Like in the use of English *almost*, Italian *quasi* or Swedish
> *nästan*. **But some expressions, on the contrary, refer to a quantity that is slightly higher than the mentioned one. Like for *-odd* in this
> example**
>
> (7) *Did you know there are loads of people outside? Must be
> 200-odd out there.* [Jens Allwood et al.; "Vagueness, unspecificity, and approximation" in S. Cantarini and W. Abraham (eds.) *Certainty-uncertainty — and the Attitudinal Space in Between*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Certainty_uncertainty_and_the_Attitudina/HgkTBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22200-odd%22%20approximate&pg=PA279&printsec=frontcover)  (2014)

---

**II. Approximately the number indicated**

(a)

> Immediately following the numeral (usually one that denotes multiples
> of ten) forming a phrase preceding the noun modified. **Now often in
> weakened use (frequently hyphenated): ‘or so’; ‘or thereabouts’** (OED)

Examining the OED's citations for this sense (1597–1995), I find it impossible to tell which of the more recent ones fall under the parent definition

> More generally: used to denote a remainder or numerical surplus **over
> and above** a ‘round number’ (as a multiple of ten or a similar unit
> such as dozen, etc.)

and which were intended by the author as "about."

(b)

> You use *odd* after a number to indicate that it is only **approximate**.
> *[informal]*
>
> How many pages was it, **500 odd**?
>
> He has now appeared in **sixty odd** films. [Collins online](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/odd)

(I would always keep the hyphen; we've all seen some very odd films.)

(c)

> Used after a number, especially a number that can be divided by ten,
> to show that **the exact number is not known**:
>
> I'd say Robert's about **40-odd** - maybe 45. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/odd)

> The most common ways of giving an **approximate** number are as follows:
> ...
> *[informal]* She's got twenty-**odd** cats.
> *Cambridge International Dictionary of English*, p.58 (1995)

(d)

> Note the following informal ways of indicating **approximate**
> numbers:
>
> *some* eight people [*some* unstressed]
> 80-***odd*** people [but not *85-odd people]
> 80 people *or so/thereabouts*
> 80 *or so* people
> *a good* eighty people ['at least 80']
>
> (R. Quirk et al.; *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, p. 395)

These five alternatives are bracketed with *['about eight']* alongside. Note that "80-odd people" is **not** qualified with ['at least 80'].

(e)

> **Approximation** is also expressed by certain grammatically distinct constructions, as in [thirty *or so*] students (coordination) or
> [*thirty-**odd***] students (affixation).
>
> (Huddlestone and Pullum; *The
> Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, p.431)

(f)

> The hyphen is important in phrases such as *twenty-odd people* (=
> **roughly** twenty), to make it clear that we are talking about **roughly** twenty people, not a score of eccentrics. [H. Fowler and J.
> Butterfield; *Fowler's Concise Dictionary of Modern English Usage*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fowler_s_Concise_Dictionary_of_Modern_En/w2NjCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fowler%20odd&pg=PA450&printsec=frontcover)
> (2016)

(g)

> **More or less**: *sixty-odd dollars*. [*Random House Dictionary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Random_House_Webster_s_Dictionary/wNuEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=random%20house%20dictionary%20odd&pg=PA499&printsec=frontcover)

(h)

> You use **odd** after a number to make it sound **vague or approximate**:
> *She must be 50 odd by now. □ We received 500 odd replies.* [*Harrap's Essential English Dictionary, p.640*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Harrap_s_essential_English_Dictionary/r20pIBUVsHcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22-odd%20after%20a%20number%22&pg=PA640&printsec=frontcover) (1966)

(i)

> Hyphen can distinguish constructions such as ...*30-odd professors* (**around** 30 professors) and 30 odd
> professors (a convocation of eccentric educators). Lisa McLendon; *The
> Perfect English Grammar Workbook*, p.170 (2017)

(j)

> We can also use the following expression to approximate numbers.
>
> *There were sixty **or so** people at the party.*
> *I saw a hundred-**odd** bicycles chained to the fence.*
> *We had **hundreds of** applications for the job.*
> *My MP3 player has a thousand songs, **or thereabouts**.* [Lewis Lansford; *Keynote Advanced, British English, Student Book*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Keynote_Advanced_British_English_Student/wGj6DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=odd%20%22or%20so%22%20approximate%20numbers&pg=PT147&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

(k)

> Cardinal numerals, like scalar properties, form a scale, and also have
> a variety of admodifies, often of complex form, that increase,
> decrease, or approximate the numerical value:
>
> Increase cardinality: *(well) over twenty people, more than twenty
> people, at least / no less than twenty people*
>
> Decrease cardinality:
> *under twenty people, fewer than twenty people, at most / no more than twenty people*
>
> **Approximate cardinality**: *(around twenty people, twenty or so people, twenty-**odd** people* [Willian Croft; *Morphosyntax: Constructions of the World's Languages*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Morphosyntax/jHB3EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=odd%20%22or%20so%22%20approximate%20numbers&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover) (2022)

---

**III. Either more than *or* approximately the number indicated**

(a)

> *[In combination]* **In the region of** or **somewhat more** than a particular number or quantity. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/odd)

(b)

> [Postpositive] [In combination] **In the region of** or **somewhat
> more than** a particular number or quantity: *She looked younger than
> her **50-odd** years*. *Oxford New American Dictionary*

(c)
From [Sheila Dooley and Ferdinand de Haan; "On the nature of the approximative expression NUM-odd*" in William D. Lewis et al. (eds.) *Time and Again: Theoretical Perspectives on Formal Linguistics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Time_and_Again/KsMRxGLEYd4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20adjective%20%22-odd%22%20means%20approximately&pg=PA45&printsec=frontcover) (2009), which I found after posting my question:

> ...
> It originated from the use of *odd* to denote a surplus or remainder,
> which usage has existed for several hundred years
> ...
> Given that Terry
> Langendon taught at the University of Arizona from 1988 until 2005
> (i.e. seventeen years), it is tempting to use the numeral *twenty*
> with an approximative measure, as in (1):
>
> (1)
> a. Terry taught at the University of Arizona for *twenty or so*
> years.
> b. Terry taught at the University of Arizona for *some twenty*
> years.
> c. Terry taught at  the University of Arizona for ***twenty-odd***
> years.
>
> Although (1a) and (b) are perfectly fine, there is a problem with
> (1c): it seems unnatural to use the expression NUM-*odd* when
> referring to a number below NUM. The present paper is a study of the
> NUM-*odd* expression.
>
> This expression may seem like a very infrequent type of phrase in
> contemporary English, but a corpus study shows that this is an
> illusion.
> ...
> It is **probably still the case** that NUM-odd when combined with lower
> level numbers (**the 'tens'**) expresses a range with **NUM as the lower
> limit**, especially when combined with nouns such as *year* (the
> prototypical instance). However, at higher levels, such as *two
> thousand-odd* **the NUM-*odd* construction is turning into a true
> approximative and can be used in the sense 'about'**.

(d)

> Expressions like “twenty-odd years,” “a dozen-odd people,” and “two
> hundred-odd mistakes” are usually written with a hyphen before the
> “odd” to indicate that **the exact number is unknown—perhaps a bit
> higher than the stated number**. If you omit the hyphen, as in “a
> dozen odd people attended my birthday party,” you risk giving the
> impression that the people who came were odd **rather than that you
> can’t be sure of the precise number of your guests**. [Paul Brians;
> *Common Errors in English Usage*](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/odd/) (2013)

(e)

> If you want to say **"about" and possibly more than a particular
> number**, you can use the phrase *or so* or the suffix -**odd**.
>
> *They
> raised $200 or so for charity.*
> *Her son must be forty-**odd** years old
> by now.* [Paul Heacock (ed.); *Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cambridge_Academic_Content_Dictionary_Re/pqlRO2jdI2gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=odd%20%22or%20so%22%20approximate%20numbers&pg=PA2&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

---

How would you know when *-odd* is being used to mean *somewhat more* than the number indicated, and what does that actually mean, since an approximate number may have been rounded up or down (or do some folks still *always* round down)?

---

> 'Oh. Well, I've been telling her, it's only natural he's getting a
> bit forgetful,' Greg told Strike dismissively. **'What's he now,
> eighty-odd**?'
> '**Seventy-nine**,' said Lucy.
> '**Well, that's eighty-odd, isn't it?**' said Greg, heading for the loaf of banana bread.
> J.K. Rowling, writing
> as Robert Galbraith; *Running Grave*, p.103 (2023)

Comment: With a round number (30, 250, 4000), it means 'and change', i.e, always over the amount, but not much over, in context.

Comment: No, I don't think anyone would use 'odd' with a figure that wasn't a round number.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. 298 is "about 300" or "almost 300" but not "300-odd". That might be 305-350 or so. The point is that the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment for @John Lawler. I'm still confused about the definitions that use *in the region of, approximately, or so, thereabouts*.

Comment: Round-number-odd usually means more than, but it also means less than the next round number up. So 50-odd is less than 60.

Comment: One is tempted to ask what's so weird about the odd pages.  Or maybe "How many even pages were there?"

Comment: Quirk's << 80-odd people [but not *85-odd people] = 80 people or so/thereabouts >> vs Collins's << Used to designate an indefinite quantity more than the quantity specified in round numbers >> proves, I believe, that the term is ill-defined. People tend to cherry-pick definitions, though. // If I say "I estimated 350-odd people were at the garden party", does it make sense to believe I'm absolutely sure 350 is the lower bound?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree. I think many people believe there is just one meaning when they read or use the construction.  For advertising purposes and to make a point when a higher number is favorable, I wouldn't blink at rounding up. However, I think I looked it up after you used it in a comment because there was something nagging at the back of my mind.

Comment: This use of *odd* here is just **more or less**, isn't it?? Such a tempest in a teapot ....

Comment: @Lambie Evidently this is *more or less* the meaning now, but it didn't used to be and apparently still isn't for some. M-W was the first definition I checked. According to them it doesn't mean *more or less*, but only *more*.

Comment: The research paper you’ve added seems like the best possible answer to your question. Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: I thought about that, but I wasn't convinced it was sufficient--I see it as evidence of use/descriptive. Part of the issue is whether some dictionary editors are unaware of the approximative sense, or are, but don't think it is common enough or don't want to sanction it. I'll ask @EdwinAshworth

Comment: I don't think native speakers consciously think of it as "the actual quantity must be greater than X" - that's more of a side effect of what's really going on:  simply dropping the words for the least significant figures. Because of the way English numbers are expressed, that just happens to equate to rounding down. (I suspect if English defined the words for 391 as "four hundred minus nine" instead of "three hundred and ninety-one" then things might work very differently.) FWIW, in my part of the AmE world, we're much more likely to say "three hundred *and* some-odd" - I suppose "and"="plus"

Comment: @Neil_UK said "Round-number-odd usually means more than, but it also means less than the next round number up. So 50-odd is less than 60." OK for the 'tens, but what's the next round number up if I say "6000-odd page"? 7000? 6100? 6010? I wouldn't use it for, say, 6890.

Comment: @DjinTonic Definitely less than 7000, unlikely to be limited by 6010, isn't language wonderfully imprecise? And that's why I commented rather than attempt an answer.

Comment: I'd say there's a lot of truth in Dooley and de Haan's conclusion, including the 'works differently for higher numbers, nowadays' refinement. But what is a 'higher number'? I wouldn't have a knee-jerk reaction to someone saying 'There were 150-odd people on the beach' and then finding that CCTV footage showed that there had been 148. I think insisting on the 'lower bound' definition is over-prescriptive nowadays, but that one can expect to encounter this, including among the well educated. Bottom line: ill-defined; tread warily ... only use where precision isn't a matter of life and death.

Comment: It might also help to distinguish "*300 odd*" from "*300 even*". While not in general use, "*300 even*" implies "*exactly 300*" as in "*I paid $300 even for that horse*".

Comment: Or even that other meaning: you get your 300 odd pages, you flip them over, load them back into the tray and print your 300 even pages onto the other side for a manual collation :)

Comment: Please consider consolidating changes to fewer revisions.

Comment: For me it means that I can't remember the actual number but it was at least the number I specified. I was born in Sussex and lived there for 30 odd years.

Comment: To be "thirty odd", surely the number needs to be 30+ for it to make sense'? If the number were 29, then it can't be "thirty odd" because there is no 'thirty' involved.

Comment: @RoaringFish If you accept the meaning,  it's no different from saying you have about 30, some thirty,  roughly 30, around 30, approximately 30. These all work for 29 actual items, but mention 30.

Comment: There is more to it than mentioning thirty. Your examples all have a modifier marking imprecisions. "Thirty odd" doesn't. See how it looks like a number -  thirty one or thirty two? That is deliberate. It is essentially "thirty [unknown number]" so using it for twenty nine doesn't really work because twenty nine is not thirty something, AKA thirty odd.

Comment: @RoaringFish You are working backwards. The  original mean of "30 odd" *was* "30 and odd" or thirty and  some small, not very significant amount *over 30*. The meaning has, for some,  changed or we grew up with this different meaning. But it's illogical to think "the meaning can't change because it didn't used to mean that." Look at the reputable dictionaries and grammars sanctioning "about".

Comment: Elephants are grey, but not everything that is grey is also an elephant. Thirty odd is about thirty, but not everything that is about thirty is also thirty odd.

Comment: This is  a great question. I was startled to see so many authorities asserting that 'XX-odd' can **only** mean 'XX and a little more'. I have always taken it to mean 'approximately XX'—although it certainly can mean 'XX and a little more' in some instances. In my own speech, I tend to use 'about XX' when I mean 'approximately XX' and 'XX-plus' when I mean 'at least XX and (possibly) a little more'. I suspect that the understanding of 'XX-odd' that people grew up with colors how narrow and precise they consider its proper meaning to be—prescriptivism at its finest and most natural.

Answer (score 39):

I usually understand **odd** as being *in addition to* an amount, rather like a remainder. However, it can also mean an approximation, and there isn't a sure-fire way to tell the two apart.

The sense of *odd* as *additional* is deep in the history of the word. For instance, the Oxford English Dictionary gives this for its first definition of [*odd* (adj., n.1., and adv)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130399):

> 1. Of an individual: that is *one in addition to a pair, or to an even number*; remaining over after distribution or division into pairs; *constituting a unit in excess of an even number*.

In other words, an *odd number* is odd because it is one in excess to an even number. That also explains uses like the *odd man out*, the one person unpaired in a larger group.

That sense of odd influences the more generic meaning of *odd* as a remainder or approximate (definitions 3 and 4). Two definitions highlight the potential for polysemy between an additional sense and an approximate sense:

**Odd as additional**

> 4. More generally: used to denote *a remainder or numerical surplus over and above a ‘round number’* (as a multiple of ten or a similar unit such as dozen, etc.), and thus becoming virtually an indefinite cardinal number of lower denomination than the round number named.

**Odd as approximate**

> 4c. Immediately following the numeral (usually one that denotes multiples of ten) forming a phrase preceding the noun modified. *Now often in weakened use (frequently hyphenated): ‘or so’; ‘or thereabouts’*.

There's the rub. Under additional usage, *40-odd* means 40 plus a smaller number. Under approximate use, *40-odd* is 40 or so. There isn't a great way to distinguish between the two, but there are a couple of ideas:

1. Is it older writing? *Odd* probably means an addition. For instance, at the time Otto Jespersen wrote part VII of *[A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Modern_English_Grammar_on_Historical_P/qRWfYiH4CywC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=hundred-odd&pg=PA586&printsec=frontcover)* (first published 1954), he only acknowledged *odd* as a quantifier: "a number is a little higher than that denoted by the numeral."
2. Is it newer writing? Be less precise in assumption. For instance, the French/English answer book *Grammaire Anglaise* (Florent Gusdorf) lists the following gloss for *hundred-odd*: "A hundred-odd people, a hundred or so people." If you don't have insight into how the author uses *-odd*, don't assume the usage is precisely *more than*.

Comment: Well argued.  You make the case for definitions along the lines of group III.

Comment: Think *odds and ends*.

Comment: Thanks to @tchrist, who always makes the odd comment :-)

Comment: It's curious that both major grammars, Quirk and Huddlestone & Pullum, have the approximation-only sense.

Comment: @DjinTonic I agree. Maybe they're trying to capture language as it is used at present (description) rather than language as it was used or as they'd prefer to use it. Since approximation is the less restrictive way to understand current usage, perhaps they stick with that. Pam Peters (*The Cambridge Guide to English Usage*) also emphasizes approximation only.

Comment: Possibly, however, I just added as I (f) the grammar by  Biber, Johansson and Leech (first published 1999) that has *only* "over." Go figure!

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: If the "approximately" meaning is becoming more common, perhaps that's in place as well as time. "Plus a few" seems to be primary in the UK, though I don't think you could be accused of lying if your 30-odd guests turned out to be 29. Maybe there's even a suggestion of asymmetric uncertainty: from just under the stated round number to just under the next

Comment: Saying "NUM odd" is an approximation, but it is a logical fallacy to think that this means all approximations are all also "NUM odd". Entailment doesn't work like that. "He was murdered" entails that he is dead, but "he is dead" does not entail that he was murdered.

Answer (score 13):

I've only used "-odd" myself and have seen it used by others to mean

> With a relatively small **indefinite** number over that specified (usually in hyphenated compounds) *twenty-odd children*.

in both speech and print. But I learned its meaning from contextual clues, and it's interesting that the dictionary lists multiple meanings/uses!

Comment: 'In the dictionary' would be an unfortunate misappropriation of a generic usage. The whole point here is that **different** (respectable) **dictionaries** (and grammars) disagree in what they license based on descriptive principles.

Comment: Note also that "the dictionary" of English doesn't exist (unlike more prescriptive languages), so it's usually wise to state _which_ dictionary you're using as reference for any given answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can be sure that others are always using it to mean an indefinite number over, because, from what I've seen, contextual clues are very often missing entirely. In those cases, you aren't seeing anything that *refutes* your understanding, but these instances  do not *confirm* it either.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you dug up quite a number of authoritive references supporting either, so the answers will end up more or less a poll.

For what it's worth, I only know 300-odd in the meaning "300 and then some".  A similarly colloquial (but probably slighly less formal) way of expressing "about 300" would be 300-ish.

Comment: Was looking to see who mentioned "-ish".  Its existence with equally short length makes it completely unnecessary to use "-odd" for approximation (one might be tempted to use "-odd" if the only alternative were "or thereabouts" as suggested in the source Taliesin quoted, a significantly longer turn of phrase)

Comment: @BenVoigt *-ish* is the highly versatile way to make almost anything approximative, but with so many choices-- some/roughly/about 300 pages; 300 pages, give or take; nearly 300 pages  (if under)--why resort to it, given there's no good place to put it: 300 pages-ish?, 300-ish pages? *300 pages, -ish* works only as a spoken afterthought.

Comment: @DjinTonic: It's *300-ish pages*, exactly parallel to *300-odd pages*.

Answer (score 6):

Any time I can think of that I've heard someone use "-odd" this way, it was used with a round number and meant "plus some". Like "500-odd pages" meaning "somewhat more than 500 pages".

If someone said "500-odd pages" and it turned out the actual number was 498, I'd say it was inaccurate to say "500-odd" but not jarringly so. Such an expression is clearly approximately so if you're guessing a little high, no big deal.

I've never heard someone use "-odd" with a non-round number, like "237-odd". I suppose if I heard that I'd take it to mean at least 237  and probably a little more. But it's just not something that people normally say.

I wouldn't be surprised to hear someone use it with some other unit, like "5 dozen-odd". But I don't recall ever hearing that.

In general, if you want to say "about 500", where it might be 10 or 20 or whatever either way, say "about 500". I'd reserve "500-odd" for "more than 500".

Comment: "5 dozen-odd" would be extremely odd, as in never heard before and too cumbersome. "A good 5 dozen" would be common.

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree it's cumbersome, but "[There were not 10,000-dozen-odd good forks. There were 10,000-dozen-odd poor forks.](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qtw7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA680&lpg=PA680&dq=%22dozen+odd%22&source=bl&ots=C3DsX04U2j&sig=ACfU3U11nj17kRHEkfo-0_0Jvt_Uc5BYyg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRz4HHrPr2AhW1D0QIHRYpBnAQ6AF6BAgnEAM#v=onepage&q=%22dozen%20odd%22&f=false)"

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree, but it was mentioned in the sources that the OP quoted.

Comment: A quick search in Google Books turns up two pages of hits for [*five dozen-odd*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22five+dozen-odd%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBsLh3jIqHHkP6yPR_tHT35vNAAz5A:1649088431177&ei=rxdLYtG1Cp6lytMP8-CbqA8&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiRyZKR5fr2AhWeknIEHXPwBvUQ8NMDegQIARBA&biw=1168&bih=497&dpr=1.25), from girls and plants to incumbents and species. The OED has "A dozen-odd men in gray are in this yard."

Answer (score 0):

In such expressions as “Twenty-odd days”, “**odd**” always constitutes an excess over and above the given number, quantity, or amount.

**Odd** entered the English language in the 14th century with reference to an item that remained once a series of those items had been paired, and this item always indicated an excess.

OED:

> **A. adj.  I.  1 Of an individual: that is one in addition to a pair, or
> to an even number; remaining over after distribution or division into
> pairs; constituting a unit in excess of an even number.**
>
> 8d.   a1325  (▸c1280)    Southern Passion (Pepys 2344) (1927) 1497
> *His cloþes hi delde a ffoure..Þo was his curtel odde.* [His clothes he divided into four sets of two but his jacket was odd (left
> over/remained)]

It was also used to simply imply an excess regardless as to whether a division had taken place.

> **3.a. Used to denote a surplus over a definite sum, or a remainder (usually expressed in a lower denomination) of weight, measure, or
> money; additional, extra, remaining.**
>
> a1400 in R. H. Robbins Hist. Poems 14th & 15th Cent. (1959) 162 (MED)
> *Of twelue moneþes me wanted one & odde days nyen or ten.* [During a/the year I had lacked the odd day nine or ten times]
>
> 1859   ‘G. Eliot’ Adam Bede v. xxxvi. 418   *Her two guineas, and the odd shillings, which had a melancholy look.*

**Odd** was used to describe in a dismissive manner things of less value and that thus fell as extraneous outside the major group or amount:

> **†b. and odd: denoting an indefinite number and qualifying a noun of lower denomination in an otherwise definite expression of quantity or
> amount; ‘and some’; ‘and a few’.** Also without and. Obsolete.
>
> 1714   London Gaz. No. 5213/4   11 Foot odd Inches in the Hold.
>
> 1813   R. Wilson Private Diary I. 434   Thirty-eight thousand odd
> hundred infantry, two thousand odd hundred cavalry.
>
> **†c. (and) odd money: denoting a surplus sum of lower denomination.** Obsolete.
>
> 1447   in S. A. Moore Lett. & Papers J. Shillingford (1871) 16 (MED)
> *Thomas Montagew sholde sende me xj li. and odde mony.*
>
> 1752   H. Fielding Amelia III. viii. ii. 115   *He hath been here
> these five Weeks, at the Suit of a Bookseller, for Eleven Pound odd
> Money.*

The modern post-positional form appeared in the early part of the 18th century:

> **d. Used elliptically, simply as odd or (occasionally) odds, to denote an indeterminate surplus of a lower denomination of money,
> weight, or measure** (as in senses A. 3b   and A. 3c).
>
> 1741   S. Richardson Pamela III. xvii. 93   **The remaining Four
> Pounds odd will be a little Fund..towards the Childrens Schooling.**
>
> 1961   Listener 26 Oct. 659/2   **The £6-odd offered (per week) by
> banks and post offices, etc., to sixteen-year-old ‘O’ levellers.**

In the same time-frame as the above, a sense developed that was related to the idea of something being more than was required as it was uneven or irregular:

> **8.a. Extraneous or additional to what is reckoned or taken into account; that is not, or cannot be, reckoned, included, or coordinated
> with other things; not belonging to any particular total, set, or
> group; not forming part of a regular series; unconnected; irregular,
> casual; occurring randomly or haphazardly.**

But this also had the nuance that it was “extra” – beyond the ordinary, and hence “strange”.

> 1390? J. Mirk Instr. Parish Priests (Claud.) (1974) 198   *Loke also
> þey make non odde weddynge.* [Ensure also that they do not officiate at
> an irregular marriage.]
>
> 1966   C. Bukowski Let. 6 Apr. in Screams from Balcony (1998) 250
> *All the odd things, haircut, buy shoes, get a tooth pulled,* [etc.].
>
> 1998   Strad July 709/2   *Many pieces suffer from the odd sour note or from untidy position changes.*
>
> **†8c. Extra; given over and above.** Obsolete.

Perhaps most clearly shown in

> 1604   W. Shakespeare Hamlet v. ii. 138   *I will winne for him and I can, if not, I will gaine nothing but my shame, and the odde hits.*

Comment: But what about << 4c. Immediately following the numeral (usually one that denotes multiples of ten) forming a phrase preceding the noun modified. Now often in weakened use (frequently hyphenated): ‘or so’; ‘or thereabouts’. >>?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - an outlier... Few of the examples are easily distinguished from the main meaning. All meanings go to an approximation but the guidance is good - "and then a few more."

Comment: So one is at liberty to cherry-pick to suit what one feels is right. I'd say this is misquoting.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TinMerlin's answer, for the algorithms and SEO, I think it is fitting to point out that "odd" is sometimes a popular misspelling of "ought" and sometimes even of "aught" ("naught"), although these two are quite different in meaning, simply because they sound the same in many dialects. For example, a firearm properly labeled "30-06" is sometimes colloquially called a "thirty-odd-six", even though "odd" does not otherwise mean "zero".

If you take "odd" to be an odd spelling of "ought", your 300-odd could mean "three hundred and *ought*", or "three hundred and *something*". It would be unusual to use it to mean "three hundred and *aught*", that is, "three hundred and *nothing*".

**Ought**-how, Wikipedia's [*names for zero*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_the_number_0_in_English) entry has this to say about them both:

> "Naught" and "nought" come from the Old English "nāwiht" and "nōwiht", respectively, both of which mean "nothing". They are compounds of no- ("no") and *wiht* ("thing").[4][5][6]
>
> The words "aught" and "ought" (the latter in its noun sense) similarly come from Old English "āwiht" and "ōwiht", which are similarly compounds of a ("ever") and *wiht*. Their meanings are opposites to "naught" and "nought"—they mean "anything" or "all". (Fowler notes that "aught" is an archaism, and that "all" is now used in phrases such as "for all (that) I know", where once they would have been "for aught (that) I know".)[4][7][8]
>
> However, "aught" and "ought" are also sometimes used as names for 0, in contradiction of their strict meanings. The reason for this is a rebracketing, whereby "a nought" and "a naught" have been misheard as "an ought" and "an aught".[2][4]
>
> Samuel Johnson thought that since "aught" was generally used for "anything" in preference to "ought", so also "naught" should be used for "nothing" in preference to "nought". However, he observed that "custom has irreversibly prevailed in using 'naught' for 'bad' and 'nought' for 'nothing'". Whilst this distinction existed in his time, in modern English, as observed by Fowler and The Reader's Digest above, it does not exist today. However, the sense of "naught" meaning "bad" is still preserved in the word "naughty", which is simply the noun "naught" plus the adjectival suffix "-y". This has never been spelled "noughty".[2]
>
> The words "owt" and "nowt" are used in Northern English. For example, if tha does owt for nowt do it for thysen: if you do something for nothing do it for yourself.[9]